# Setting class of an Scala object to a field of a Java annotation

Tags: java, scala, reflection, annotations

I have a Java annotation like the following:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConvertWith {
  Class<? extends Converter> converterClass();
}
```

And I have several converter **objects** written in **Scala**. For example, *IntConverter* is shown below:

```
object IntConverter extends Converter {
  def convert(str: String) = str.toInt
}
```

I want to use these objects like the following to associate them with fields:

```
class SampleAction {
  @ConvertWith(converterClass = classOf[IntConverter])
  val x: Int = 0
}
```

However, Scala cannot find the converter class because *scalac* compiles objects differently.

I have also tried the following ways but none of them worked:

```
// error: class type required but IntConverter.type found
@ConvertWith(converterClass = classOf[IntConverter.type])

// error: annotation argument needs to be a constant...
@ConvertWith(converterClass = IntConverter.getClass)
```

Is there a way to do this? Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would stick to classes for java interop

Comment: You can also have both: `class IntConverter extends Converter ...; object IntConverter extends IntConverter`.